weighted matroid intersection theorem
I am trying to prove the result in Section 6 of this lecture note.
It just says the proof is similar to the non-weighted version without giving it. (A same non-weighted version proof is here, which has illustrating pictures.)
First I don't understand the what is "the shortest augmenting path based on $\ell(x)$", i.e., what is the weighted length of a directed path $P$ on vertices $v_1v_2\dots v_k$?
Is that $\sum_{i=1}^k\ell(v_i)$ or $\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}(\ell(v_{i+1})-\ell(v_i))=\ell(v_k)-\ell(v_1)$. Neither makes sense to me, as when $w\equiv 1$ (the non-weighted version), neither of them gives the length of a path. Somehow the former one may make more sense, as it is the difference of weights between the vertices on the two sides, but it can be negative.
In the non-weighted proof, if there is a shortest $X_1-X_2$ path $P$, then the symmetric difference of $P$ and the current independent set gives an independent set of larger cardinality. For the non-weighted version, if we use the first definition of "weighted length" and the shortest length is negative, then we get an independent set of larger cardinality and weight.
Then in the next step, we should show if there is no $X_1-X_2$ path of negative length, then the current common independent set is of maximum weight. I have no idea how to prove this. What is a criteria of a maximum weight common independent set?
